# ASP.Net MVC - How to dynamically add items to an object and bind it to the controller to store in a database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, data-binding, relational-database

I would like to dinamically add and remove items from a POCO Object and store it on a related table. for instance:

```
class Contact{
    [Key]
    public int id {get; set;}
    [Required] public string name {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<Phone> phones{get; set;}
}

class Phone{
    [Key]
    public int id {get;set;}
    [Required] public string phone_type {get; set;}
    [Required] public string phone_number {get; set;}
}
```

where Contact is able to have a lot of phones.

The Contact Edit View is like this:

```
@model SGD.Models.Contact
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.name)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.name)

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.phones)
<div id="phones"></div>

<a href="#" onclick="addPhone()">Add new phone</a>

<script>
    function addPhone() {
        $.ajax({url: "/Phones/_Phone",
             cache: false,
             success: function(html) { $("#phones").append(html);}}
    )}
</script>
```

the "Add new phone" link button append this partial view inside #phones div

```
@model SGD.Models.Phone
@{
    Layout = null;
}

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id)

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.phone_type)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.phone_type)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.phone_type)

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.phone_number)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.phone_number)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.phone_number)
```

But I Don't know how to handle and bind the post data in the controller and store the contact and the related phone records on DB. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would check out [this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/) by Phil Haack.

You will need some mechanism in your javascript to apply indexing to your phone partial, but in a nutshell your partial needs to look more like this:

```
@model SGD.Models.Phone
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<input name="phones[0].id" style="display:none;"/>

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.phone_type)
<input name="phones[0].phone_type" />

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.phone_number)
<input name="phones[0].phone_number" />
```

As for the database part, I am assuming you are using Entity Framework code-first based on the models you've shown. There are some problems with your code-first models in that case. Read this [msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698.aspx) to learn how to properly construct code-first models for different types of relationships. I'm guessing you intend to have a one-to-many relationship between contacts and phones, where one contact may have many phones. In that case, your models should be as follows:

```
class Contact{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string name {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Phone> phones{get; set;}
}

class Phone{
    [Key]
    public int id {get;set;}
    public string phone_type {get; set;}
    public string phone_number {get; set;}
    public Contact contact { get; set; }
}
```

From there, use your context to add new phones to the appropriate contacts like so in your AddPhone action method:

```
public ActionResult AddPhone(int ContactId)
{
    var newPhone = new Phone();
    Contact ct = ctx.Contacts.Find(ContactId);
    ct.Phones.Add(newPhone);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
    return View(newPhone);
}
```

You will also need to implement EditPhone and DeletePhone actions.

As for the [Required] attributes, you either need to remove them or re-think your view entirely. You can't just "addphone" with required attributes without taking any input first. You need to get the input from the user before you can bind it, and I currently don't see any effort on your part toward that end.

Comment: What the "enter code here" line means?

Comment: Just a mistake from the SO editor's code highlighter, fixed

Comment: What about the "@validationMessageFor" statement??

Comment: You don't have any data annotations on your model so that validation message won't do anything. If you're interested in server-side validation, then I suggest you read up on that topic and ask a new question about it if you're still confused.

Comment: I edited the question adding the [Required] Annotation. I'd removed a lot of irrelevant annotations and data for this example. [Required was one of them]

Comment: @DanielSantos I'm afraid you're going to need to put in a bit more initiative, research, and effort if you want to make progress on this. I only came here to answer 1 question, not teach a full course in asp.net mvc and front-end web development.

Comment: Sorry about that I really appreciate your help.